# how to display dollar format for decimals in razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am trying to display a dollar format for my razor list view. It displays decimals fe 100.17 but I am looking for $100.17 format in my list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount))
   </td>
</tr>
```

I got a gutfeeling I need some kind of htmlextension for this but could not find this. Any other ways of doing this?

Comment: With the TextBoxFor method you can specify a format string `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, "{0:C2}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate the property (Amount) in the model itself like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```